# React useReducer sets the whole state as undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context, use-reducer

I'm having a problem where updating my Context state with a reducer, sets the whole state as undefined... This is my code:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AccountReducer, initialState);
```

**The call to the Dispatch**

```
 dispatch({
  type: SET_TOKEN,
  payload: token
})
```

**And the reducer**

```
  const AccountReducer = (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
    case SET_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload
      }

    default:
      break
  }
};
```

After I make the dispatch the whole state is set to undefined.... Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

A reducer must return the new state value each time it is called. In your `default` case you return nothing (`undefined`), which will be your next state.

Simply return the last state in the default case:

```
 const AccountReducer = (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
    case SET_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload
      }

    default:
      return state; // Return the same value passed in to be used as the next state
  }
};
```

I'm working under the assumption that `SET_TOKEN` is a variable shared between the dispatch call and the reducer. If they do not match, this will also cause problems.